# How to upload laravel 5 project in Linux hosting server?

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5

I am trying to upload laravel 5 project to a live hosted Linux server. When I browse to a url it shows many errors.

```
Error- 404 Page Not Found
```

and

```
Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

When I check my Error log file

```
[Mon Dec 28 12:10:57 2015] [error] [client 60.243.107.196] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /home/riseyourmoney/public_html/vdl/
```

So I changed my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

There is any routing problem?

Comment: My suspicion and something for you to check: I don't think the issue is in .htaccess. It's in the apache configuration file. I bet if you tried those url from a browser on the server (eg lynx), they would work just fine.

Comment: i tried those url but its not working.